# Bash Shell: close all windows and programs UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, automator

How would I make a script to exit all programs and windows using bash shell commands and automator on a unix machine?

without using an extra program such as

```
xdotool search "" windowkill %@
```

Comment: We all are here to learn, so please always show input, expected output samples in your post too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

command=$(ps aux | awk '{print $1,$2}' | grep $USER)

for i in $command; do
    kill -9 ${i};

done
```

Comment: Won't this kill your own script (i.e. bash instance that runs it)? As it will be included in the list of PIDs you retrieve with `ps aux`. Maybe not what you wanted.